# IMFTransform Configuration

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, com, media, ms-media-foundation

I want to write an `IMFTransform` that will blend 2 audio streams. But ideally I'd like to apply it in a stream-specific fashion. For example, I'd like to blend only a certain duration of the streams. To reiterate, the exact timing and duration would be different in each instance.

The problem is that I don't see any kind of function in the `IMFTransform` interface that allows me to pass this information. Am I missing something? Should I extend the `IMFTransform` interface with some custom methods or functions? What is the acceptable way forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to extend `IMFTransform` interface, this is not how things are supposed to be done. You typically implement another private interface on the same transform class and make it available using regular COM `IUnknown::QueryInterface` (or in some sense similar `IMFGetService`). The application would create an instance of transofrm, query this additional interface and pass necessary configuration.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to me.  I'm going to have to do some research on nested interfaces and using `QueryInterface`.  This is farther down the COM rabbit hole than I've ever been.

Comment: Note that it's not nesting. It's another interface implemented side by side.

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar approach with this projet :[MFSkVideoRenderer](https://github.com/mofo7777/MFNode/tree/master/MFSkVideoRenderer)

- VideoShaderEffect.idl : declare COM object (interface/method/library)
- SinkVideoRenderer.h : add public IMFVideoShaderEffect, and declare method (STDMETHOD(FunctionName)();)
- SinkVideoRenderer.cpp : implement method HRESULT CSinkVideoRenderer::FunctionName(){ return S_OK: } (could also be inlined in SinkVideoRenderer.h, if simple code)
- include : #include "VideoShaderEffect_h.h" (will be generated from .idl)
- to use inside an another program : #include "VideoShaderEffect_i.c" (will also be generated from .idl) see [MFNodePlayer](https://github.com/mofo7777/MFNode/tree/master/MFNodePlayer) for an example

You will have to learn a little about [MIDL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/midl-start-page)